# How the hell am I supposed to survive in the underworld?

Tags: terraria

The minute I reach the border of the underworld, fire imps start popping up everywhere, nuking me with fireballs from every conceivable angle. In addition, 3 huge skeleton worms show up ramming into me relentlessly.

The end result is that I'm hit by something at least a couple of times per second, knocking me around. Mining is impossible as I'm knocked into the lava if I even get close, and building some sort of fortress won't help seeing as all the monsters down here ignore walls completely.

I have 300 hp, 200 mana, full shadow armor and a nightmare pickaxe. **How the hell do people survive down here?**

Comment: possible duplicate and highly related: [How to survive an immortal imp army?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24547/how-to-survive-an-immortal-imp-army)

Comment: I'm afraid building a stone grid won't help me here, Raven Dreamer

Comment: [building an artificial meteor might](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24547/how-to-survive-an-immortal-imp-army/24569#24569).

Comment: You should also get an obsidian skull, which I believe requires some obsidian (pour water on lava) and some iron ore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Find a place where below you there's a lot of ground (ash) and hellstone (no buildings or anything where the imps can spawn on). Dig a tunnel (width 2) under you (block fireballs with a fast pickaxe) and mine until there are no visible places to spawn for imps, other than your own tunnel (which you can even fill with dirt).

Then it's easy to mine hellstone while blocking the fireballs of the few imps with your pickaxe (always face the enemy while mining). There won't be many imps since they don't have much space to spawn.

A stack of potions, magic mirror and any flail (for worms) should then be enough.

[image]

(I think the tunnel in the image is too wide, but hopefully this still makes it more clear)

Comment: fill up space in the tunnel with spare dirt and ash

Answer (score 14):

Patch 1.0.4 increased the spawn rates and maximum spawn numbers quite a bit, and the Underworld wasn't a cake walk before that.

Some general tips for surviving:

- Take less damage to avoid dying.
- Bring some excess dirt and cover up all the lava in the area, first thing you do.
- Bring a lot of health potions. At least one, maybe two full stacks.
- Bring a powerful flail-type weapon, such as the [Blue Moon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blue_Moon), to deal with the Bone Serpents. If you've already got a [Sunfury](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sunfury), even better!
- The [Muramasa](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Muramasa) is also effective against Bone Serpents, if less so; but, it helps tremendously with the Fire Imps: Its high swing speed will allow you to avoid most of their projectiles while charging at them, especially if coupled with [Feral Claws](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Feral_Claws).
- Put off dealing with the Fire Imps until they overwhelm you or a Bone Serpent spawns. If you swing your Nightmare Pickaxe constantly, you should be able to swat most of their fireballs out of the air while you're mining the precious Hellstone. For this purpose, the Molten Pickaxe is *not* recommended, since it swings slower.
- If you've established an escape route, you could try building a minimal shelter with a [Bed](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bed), so you respawn right where you were slain. If you happen to run out of health potions and cannot escape, simply tear down the [Bed](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bed) to revert to your original spawn point, then return by [Magic Mirror](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Magic_Mirror) or dying.

Comment: Blue Moon really makes things better.  Head to the dungeon to snag one!

Comment: Or go dynamite-ing the bone serpents! You'll get mad cash to boot.

Comment: The uses of Dynamite are pretty plentiful.  I think i'll use some on my next visit to the underworld :)

Comment: @Robb Getting the timing right on the Bone Serpents is kind of difficult, and you can't use TNT to mine Hellstone.

Comment: @lunboks, oh right I knew that.  Thanks for the reminder though on the Hellstone.

Comment: As an alternative to "paving" the lava with dirt, you can also simply bring a lake with you when you first visit the Underworld.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Things it would be important to have with you when you're in hell:

- An Obsidian skull. This would be extremely helpful while mining hellstone and walking on other hot blocks.
- Cross necklace. With all those enemies knocking you around, a few extra invincibility frames would help you out a lot.
- Potions. You need to make sure to keep your health up.
- Magic mirror, in case things get nasty.
- Rocket Boots/Wings/Hook, so you can move quickly and vertically.
- A ranged weapon, such as a bow or a gun, to keep those pesky demons away.

Hope my list helped!

Answer (score -1):

You probably want some hellstone from the underworld . You finally find the underworld as you enter you get nocked about like a plastic bag in the wind.
Here's my list of things that most definitely helps in the underworld.

- Lava charm as to help survive in lava with 7 seconds of invincibility to lava, the lava wading boots also help as they protect you againast lava
- If you can find fossils then make yourself some fossil armour if not, then consider making some metor armour or anything stronger as the provide good protection against the monsters in the underworld.
- Nightmare or deathbringer pickaxes are vital in gaining hellstone and breaking dungeon blocks
- A good weapon sunch as nights edge or excalabur to destroy demons and fire imps, and a sunfury or blue moon for quick damage against bomeserpents and demons.
- A space gun, sand cannon, minishark, flamethrower, and/or megashark for ranged attacks against pretty much anything
- Sticky bombs to blast through obsidian dungeon
- Preferabaly have hp of 400 and above

Hope this helps a lot of people, because I don't have this stuff yet so based off of experience I can say that this list should be the dream of underworld living.

Answer (score -2):

You should gather gold or shadow tool and weapons like the war axe of the night and the gold broadsword. You can also get a mini/mega shark to kill the boss that spawns in there. The highly recommended
Armor and tools and swords are hell stone armor a molten Pickaxe and a firey great sword

Answer (score -2):

I am having problems down there too. Find the goblin NPC, he will show up at your house. If he isn't there he's near lava somewhere, anyhow buy rocket-boots. That way you can fly over the lava AND bring a fast pick-axe for those imps. The thing that gets me is Arch Demons. Hope this helps :D

Answer (score -4):

the best tip i could give is using more dynamites and a obsidian skull/ obsidon horseshoe and atleast a pet to defend you while mining and barracades and weapons that shoot through walls and atleast a lights bane sword

Answer (score -5):

I think you should always a summoned minion such as the hornet,slime, or imp if you have hellstone. This should help keep some monsters off your back. Have something you can fly with or something that lets you walk in lava. Also have an obsidian shield to avoid being knocked into lava and being hurt when standing on hellstone. Have a fast melee weapon so you can charge imps without being hit. It would also help to have vilethorn to hit enemies through walls. Of course have lots of healing potions and even iron and obsidian skin potions if you have them to spare. It would also help to have a fast pickaxe so you don't always have to switch to sword to deal with imp fireballs. Also just make quick trips. Do not stay for prolonged periods of time so you do not get overwhelmed. Never stay in the underworld longer than you have to. After the WoF I only went back a couple of times. Hope my advice helps! :D